# Jquery: Click () to scroll specific div and hide top div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code Example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="intro">
    <a href="#" id="showfullsite"></a>
</div>

<div id="fullsite"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#showfullsite").click(function() {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#fullsite").offset().top
    }, 2000);

    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto'); 
    $('#intro').hide(2000);

});
```

Simple CSS:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hi everyone, I am not a jQuery expert. I am the beginner. So, I have a problem. I have two div wraps, one for the intro and one for full site. I am making a site like this, When I will open my site in a browser only the top `#intro` div will visible and the full site will hidden. I am using the `overflow: hidden;` to hide everything other side of the computer screen. I have a control in the `#intro` div screen to unlock the full site. So, When I will click in the control the site will scroll to `#full-site`. I am doing it using query and I am adding `$('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto');` to show the hidden part of the site. Also, I am adding `$('#intro').hide(2000);` to hide the top `#intro`.

At this time top `#intro` is hiding and the scroll effect is working. But the `#intro` div content going left side, right side when the `#intro` is hiding and the scroll effect is not going targeted id. It's going very down from the targeted div. How can I do the work properly?

Comment: For one fullsite is not an id. its a class. So either change the pound to a dot or change the class attribute to an id. Same goes for intro.

Comment: Your div is `class="intro"`, not `id`.

Comment: its overflow:hidden;  not overfolow:hidden ;

Comment: Have you linked a jQuery file?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace sorry for writing mistakes. I am using ID both HTML and jQuery. The top part is hiding perfectly now. But the scroll is going down from targeted DIV. Can you tell me how can I  fix that.

Comment: @k97513 sorry for writing mistakes. I am using ID both HTML and jQuery. The top part is hiding perfectly now. But the scroll is going down from targeted DIV. Can you tell me how can I  fix that.

Comment: @k97513 Yes. I have linked with jQuery

Comment: Does your intro div take up the entire window? And then you hide that and full site is below it? Because it seems to me if you just hide the intro and remove overflow full site should be viewable without scrolling to it.

Comment: @imGaurav sorry for writing mistakes.

Comment: @ZakirHossain I wrote how to fix 10 minutes ago... :) see my answer

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Yes. You are right. I have made the intro full window height using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry but it seems like there is a lot more going on here that is not in the original question. Other functions and html I am unaware of. I don't see full-home anywhere in your html above. Perhaps expand your question with more info. Because if all you are doing is giving intro the full height and width of window, setting overflow hidden on body, then when they click control hiding intro and removing overflow. Then at that point full site should be visible without any animated scrolling.

Comment: post whatever you are using so that it can replicate your problem

Comment: @imGaurav everything is working fine. But the scrollTop is doing problems. When I am clicking the trigger the site is scrolling, But is going down from the targeted ID. Is there any solution?

Comment: instead of js  try <a href="#fullsite" id="showfullsite">go to fullsite</a>https://jsfiddle.net/n6LLg2uw/1/

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `#fullsite` in your javascript, but `<div class="fullsite"></div>` in your HTML.
You need to change your HTML as `<div id="fullsite"></div>`.

The same error for `intro`.

Remember: for accessing to ID you should prefix with `#`, for classes you should use `.`.

You can read more about the selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

In your case I prefer the solution based on "id" and not on "classes". Infact any valid HTML document can contain many elements using the same class, but shouldn't exist more element with the same id.
This means that $(".aaa") will return a list containing any element with *aaa* class, but $("#aaa") will return the only element with *aaa* id.

Answer (score 0):

is this how you want to run the code

```js
$("#showfullsite").click(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".fullsite").offset().top
  }, 2000);

  $('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  $('.intro').hide(2000);

});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="intro">
      <a href="#" id="showfullsite">go to fullsite</a>
    </div>

    <div class="fullsite">this is fullsite</div>
  </div>
</div>
```